# How to convert osmium.osm.location cordinates to normal format coordinates in python(Pyosmium)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, pyproj, osmium

I have extracted the coordinates data from nodes using pyosmium. Though I was successful in extracting the data but the coordinates which osmium is giving is not in normal format, I tried to convert the one of the coordinates using pyproj but the output is wrong. What is the best way to convert the pyosmium(osmium.osm.location) coordinates to normal coordinates?

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,-2916285,515160418)
print(x2,y2)
given output = (-26.197433883484983, 90.0)
```